# How to create empty txt files with the name from other txt file

Tags: windows, batch, batch-file

I have a file.txt where are located the names for  file, for example
file1
file2
file3

I want to create empty txt files with this names which are located in file.txt
so i if i have 10 columns of text i need create 10 empty txt file.

How i can make it?

I know that like this command you can create empty file

```
echo.>EmptyFile.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe this possible in batch considering its major limitations, but I'll give it a shot.

This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19540089/how-to-get-the-list-of-filenames-in-a-directory-and-store-that-in-a-variable-usi

Here is some code that puts each filename in a directory into an array, you could then add some code that uses those filenames as a base and adds up to those:

```
@echo off
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
:: Load the file path "array"
for /f "tokens=1* delims=:" %%A in ('dir /s /b^|findstr /n "^"') do (
  set "file.%%A=%%B"
  set "file.count=%%A"
)

:: Access the values
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
for /l %%N in (1 1 %file.count%) do echo !file.%%N!
```

Personally, I would make a file simply called `file.txt` and use that as my base filename to create new files with.